# Помогите разобраться с учебным примером из книги Философия Java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.
Есть пример из главы Интерфейсы - Интерфейсы как средство адаптации:

```
    //: interfaces/RandomWords.java
// Реализация интерфейса для выполнения требований метода
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomWords implements Readable {
  private static Random rand = new Random(47);
  private static final char[] capitals =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
  private static final char[] lowers =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
  private static final char[] vowels =
    "aeiou".toCharArray();
  private int count;
  public RandomWords(int count) { this.count = count; } 
  public int read(CharBuffer cb) {
    if(count-- == 0)
      return -1; // Признак конца входных данных
    cb.append(capitals[rand.nextInt(capitals.length)]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      cb.append(vowels[rand.nextInt(vowels.length)]);
      cb.append(lowers[rand.nextInt(lowers.length)]);
    }
    cb.append(" ");
    return 10;  // Количество присоединенных символов
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new RandomWords(10));
    while(s.hasNext())
      System.out.println(s.next());
  }
}
```

Не могу понять, почему выполнятеся метод read, хотя он нигде не вызывается.

Алгоритм, как я понял, происходит следующим образом:
Создаётся ссылка на объект Scanner, создаётся объект Scanner, и в конструктор создаётся и передаётся объект RandomWords. Далее магия для меня - вызывается hasNext() объекта Scanner и непонятно, что именно дальше происходит.
Я работал со Scanner, когда в конструктор передавался потом ввода или файл. И там было понятно, что это будет следующее значение. И дальше считывание.
Что происходит в этом случае, может кто-то объянить? Я просто не понимаю, как это работает и почему вызывается метод read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае очень помогло бы пройтись отладчиком по исходникам класса `Scanner` (JDK всегда поставляется с исходниками всех классов из стандартной библиотеки, они лежат в архиве `src.zip` в папке с JDK). Там вы бы увидели, что в методе `hasNext()` класса `Scanner` таки вызывается метод `read()` класса `RandomWords`, экземпляр которого вы передали в `Scanner` при создании. Аналогично, метод `read()` класса `RandomWords` вызывается и при вызове метода `next()` класса `Scanner`.

Передавая в конструктор класса `Scanner` класс, реализующий интерфейс `Readable` (в вашем случае - экземпляр класса `RandomWords`) вы даёте `Scanner`'у источник, из которого он будет считывать данные посредством вызова метода `read()` этого класса. Согласно документации, такой класс должен при вызове метода `read()` записать в переданный `CharBuffer` прочитанные данные и вернуть либо количество прочитанных байт, либо -1 если ничего не было прочитано (конец ввода).